# Jquery Validate Single message on multiple rule failure

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using Jquery Validate to validate my form.

Here is my rules JSON

```
{ 
   "maxlength":"10",
   "email":"true",
   "minlength":"6"
}
```

and here is my messages JSON

```
{ 
   "maxlength":"Last Name length must be less than 10 characters",
   "email":"Last Name is an invalid email address.",
   "minlength":"Last Name length must be greater than 6 characters"
}
```

This gives one error message if a respective rule fails.

What I want is, if someone types "a", then it should fails 2 rules i.e. minlength and email, so at that time the message should be

```
Last Name length must be greater than 6 characters and Last Name is an invalid email address.
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Post what you have tried to achieve this.

Comment: Write your own custom validation during form submit, jquery validate runs step by  step, so you'll be able to see just the first validation it failed.

Comment: you need a custom rule as per your requirements

Comment: This plugin was designed to evaluate each rule one at a time.   You'll need to use the `.addMethod()` method to write a rule that combines all three of these requirements.

Answer (score -1):

Create a loop that validates any rule, and then add any error to an array (in the example, I used `errors` as the array).
After finishing the loop contents, use a similar code to handle the error codes, and join them by using JavaScript's `join()` function with the word "And" (+spaces) as the devider:

```
error_message = errors.join(' And ');
```

Comment: Working example?  I suspect this is not going to play nice with this plugin, which uses a single message container, replaces the text as needed, and toggles visibility based on validity.   Since the validation plugin evaluates one rule at a time as each rule is satisfied, you're going to have to bypass the plugin to achieve this loop... at that point, might as well just write a custom validation function negating the need for this plugin in the first place.